# Designing a metrics collection service

Tags: architecture, metrics, system-design

Are there best practices for designing a service that exposes an `Increment(metric_name)` endpoint that can be called from any service with any `metrics_name`, and have a live dashboard (with a ~1 hour granularity) to see trends in the metrics?

I'm mostly curious what would be an appropriate storage system for it, given that the service should be highly scalable.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if we are supposed to mention specific software, but Prometheus project at https://prometheus.io/ could offer what you are looking for out of the box.  it is a time series database designed for recording and querying metrics.  If not it could offer you some insights for your own solution.

(I am in no way affiliated with  the Prometheus project)